# Inserting row in dataset using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, insert, dataset, mahapps.metro

I am getting no errors, but in the output I get

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll

My code is as follows:

```
tBLORDERViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tBLORDERViewSource")));
DataRow tblRow = mDataSet.TBLORDER.NewRow();
tblRow["STATUS"] = "Pending";
tblRow["MYFIELD"] = "test";
mDataSet.TBLORDER.Rows.Add(tblRow);
MessageBox.Show("test");
mANTISDataSetTBLORDERSTableAdapter.Update(mDataSet.TBLORDER);
```

The application doesn't crash, the UI just goes blank and I can close the form and continue to use the application. if I comment out              `mDataSet.TBLORDER.Rows.Add(tblRow);` I can see the UI but it obviously doesn't add the record. When its not commented out, the `messagebox.show("test")` doesn't appear, so the code definitely doesn't continue. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Do you handle the RowChanging event?

Comment: What is the entire exception message?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, used a try/catch and found that one of the fields was exceeding the field limit. thanks